# Is there a set of restrictions I can use to simulate functional programming in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I was watching a talk on clean code by Misko Hevery, and he mentioned trying to write a program with no if statements in them (well, as few as humanly possible) in order to simulate working on... Smalltalk or some such language, where polymorphism is preferred over inline conditional behavior.

To my limited understanding, functional programming is hard for only-imperative-so-far programmers like me - because our state changing methodologies don't have a way to be expressed in functional programs. A function only takes a value and returns a value and knows nothing about state.

I have also seen JS being hailed as being able to support a functional model.

So is there a simple set of restrictions, similar to my first paragraph, which will enable me to try out the functional paradigm in a language I know and love - rather than learn a full new language (I'll do that eventually but I want to try the ethos right now)?

Comment: I'm really looking forward to seeing what types of answers this gets. Personally, I feel it might be easier to learn a little bit of a functional language, before implementing it in Javascript. Try [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). The basics are not difficult, and will help you overcome the hurdle of thinking functionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two meanings to the term "functional programming".

The first meaning is the ability of a program to manipulate functions. Not all languages can do this but javascript is one of the languages that can. Languages that can assign functions to variables, pass functions to arguments and return functions are called functional programming languages so javascript is functional as is.

In this sense, if you look at any modern javascript code with prevalent use of callbacks then you're already doing functional programming.

The second meaning of functional programming is the style of programming where the primary method of program composition is functions rather than variables. In this sense almost any language can be used in a functional style by avoiding variable assignments and loop structures (use recursion instead).

When you look at the functional community, what they mean by functional is the first meaning plus a very strong version of the second meaning -- that is, variables are not only avoided but banned. Languages like Haskell don't have the concept of variables. To handle side-effects and mutable state like I/O they use a concept called monads.

You don't have to go that far. Classical functional languages like Lisp and Forth allowed variables. You just have to avoid them where possible.

Lisp and Forth style functional programming is heavily driven by processing lists/arrays without assigning anything to temporary variables. To some people, this style is easier to read. Where in imperative style you'd do this:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = 0;
for (var i=0;i=a.length;i++) {
    b += a[i] * 2;
}
// result is in b
```

in functional style you'd do this:

```
[1,2,3].
    map(function(x){return x*2}).
    reduce(function(x,y){return x+y},0);
```

Conceptually, functional style makes it look like you're applying filters to the array instead of iterating through the array. If you've ever used command line tools like `grep` then you'd find this concept very familiar.

Notice that we haven't introduced any variable assignments at all in the functional style.

The three core array methods/functions in the functional style are: `map`, `reduce` and `filter`. With them you can avoid something like 90% of for-loops.

Comment: Cool, slebetman! So looks like if I (1) avoid variable assignment and mutation as much as possible, and use function arguments instead and (2) avoid loops in favor of function recursion - I'll be forced to discover functional patterns?

Comment: That's my ultimate goal - create a situation where tinkering leads me to bottom-up learning of these patterns like 'currying' and 'function composition' instead of top-down learning and then applying.

Comment: It's not that functional programmers mean that *variables* are banned, but that *side effects* are banned. In your example, `var a = [1, 2, 3]` is perfectly fine, and just a convenient way of giving a name to a value you intend to use multiple times. (This is also pretty directly expressible in Haskell with a `let` expression, complicating the claim that Haskell doesn't have variables).

Comment: Aha, but in Haskell you can't then re-let a to be `[4,5,6]` can you? That's not a variable then, it's just a macro (in the C sense, not in the lisp sense). That's not `a=b` that's `#define a b`. A "vari"able is by definition a side effect. A constant is not "vari"able thus is not strictly speaking a variable in the traditional sense.

Comment: I do not agree with `The only "clean" way to create variables in the functional style is to declare function arguments`, but perhaps I just don't understand -- what do you mean by that?  In what way is `let` not clean?

Comment: @MattFenwick: Just forgetfulness on my part. I didn't think of let. I was thinking more along the lines of how temp variables are used in imperative languages.

Comment: @MattFenwick & Ben: removed the sentence form my answer

Comment: @siebetman, the notion of "variable" does not imply side-effects, let alone traditionally. Ask any mathematician, they invented the term. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Great question.

For an in-depth answer, check out this classic (and awesome) paper by John Hughes -- [Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/whyfp90.pdf).

First, Hughes explains what functional programming is *not* about, and cites some weak arguments that proponents of FP use.  Good stuff (but too long to quote here).

Second, Hughes explains what FP is about:

> It is now generally accepted that modular design is the key to successful programming, and recent languages such as Modula-II [6] and Ada [5] include features specifically designed to help improve modularity. However, there is a very important point that is often missed. When writing a modular program to solve a problem, one first divides the problem into subproblems, then solves the subproblems, and finally combines the solutions. **The ways in which one can divide up the original problem depend directly on the ways in which one can glue solutions together. Therefore, to increase one’s ability to modularize a problem conceptually, one must provide new kinds of glue in the programming language.** Complicated scope rules and provision for separate compilation help only with clerical details — they can never make a great contribution to modularization.
>
> **We shall argue in the remainder of this paper that functional languages provide two new, very important kinds of glue. We shall give some examples of programs that can be modularized in new ways and can thereby be simplified. This is the key to functional programming’s power — it allows improved modularization. It is also the goal for which functional programmers must strive — smaller and simpler and more general modules, glued together with the new glues we shall describe.**

(emphasis mine)

So to get back to the original question, in order to do FP in Javascript, you'll want to build programs by implementing separate modules, then gluing them together.  Javascript comes with some nice glue, and you can build even more glue on your own -- check out [combinators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7534575/894284).

You should try to avoid features that prevent you from using glue to combine modular pieces of code, for example:

- mutable state -- especially if it's global
- statements -- you can't pass `while`-loops as function arguments
- some kinds of syntax, such as operators or property access -- you can't assign `+` to a variable or pass it as an argument

(These issues can, of course, be mitigated to a certain extent -- check out Javascript FP libraries for examples.)

On the other hand, features that aren't functions -- such as classes, objects, inheritance, prototypes, etc. -- don't necessarily stop you from using Javascript's glue, so there's no reason, from an FP standpoint, not to use them.